# Tracking e-mail and Insert into MySQL Data Base

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, email

I want to track emails from a mailer sent using third party tool. Code Implemented in **PHP/MySQL**
I used image tracking method to do so. I can track IP, Host, Date and Time with the code below, but I don't know how to call an email into a variable.

Please help me with the code.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

@ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'db_username', 'dbpwd', 'mydb');


if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

//echo 'Error: Could not connect to the database..';

//exit;

}


if (!empty($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {

$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

$date = date("Y-m-d");

$time = date("H:i:s");
//$email = trim("email");


$sql = "INSERT INTO mydb.emailstats (id,ip,host,referrer,date,time) VALUES (null,'$ip','$host','$referrer','$date','$time');";



$db->query($sql);

}

header( 'Content-type: image/gif' );

echo chr(71).chr(73).chr(70).chr(56).chr(57).chr(97).

chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(128).chr(0).

chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).

chr(33).chr(249).chr(4).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).

chr(0).chr(0).chr(44).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).chr(0).

chr(1).chr(0).chr(1).chr(0).chr(0).chr(2).chr(2).

chr(68).chr(1).chr(0).chr(59);

?>
```

Image Tracking Code is

```
<img src="ttp://www.pulpandpaper-technology.com/pulppaperadmin/images/logo.gif?id=51&email=!*EMAIL*!" width="0" height="0" border="0" />
```

The "email" in the image tag is what I want to track

Answer (score 0):

logo.gif should be a PHP script to do that. you can enable it by below script in htaccess for example if you are using apache as web server

```
<Files "/path/to/directory">
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .gif
</Files>
```

Use

```
$_GET['email'] ,  $_GET['id']
```

to get the values and run above inserting code.

Note: Many email clients strip out that img tag for security reasons. Also many email clients disable image by default. so Stats you get by image tracking is never 100% accurate.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr. Kiran, sorted out the error. In the image track code method, I missed 'h' in the source it should be <img src="http://......." />. Thank you for your help, anyways i come to know a new point from your answer.